# Python - add one dictionary to another

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to update one dictionary with another in Python, but if there are some same arguments, their values should be added.
For example:

```
a = {"word_1" : 1, "word_2": 2}
b = {"word_2" : 5, "word_3": 7}
```

Output must be:

```
{"word_1" : 1, "word_2": 7, "word_3": 7}
```

I have googled a lot, but in most answers values rewrites, I want to add them
Here is my solution:

```
    for i in a.keys():
        if i in b.keys():
            b[i] += a[i]
        else:
            b[i] = a[i]
```

Is there most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is a special kind of dictionary for counting objects.

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({"word_1" : 1, "word_2": 2})
b = Counter({"word_2" : 5, "word_3": 7})
print(a + b)
```

prints

```
Counter({'word_2': 7, 'word_3': 7, 'word_1': 1})
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
{k: a.get(k, 0) + b.get(k, 0) for k in set(list(a.keys()) + list(b.keys()))}
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'dict_keys'

Comment: @OleksandrPryhoda, sorry didn't test on Python3, please try again, I've updated my answer